# git stash -- <files> removing untracked files

Tags: git

Today at work, one of my colleagues noticed that doing a git stash while providing the file path removes the untracked files.

> git stash -- src/

This command removes the untracked files and does not recover them after stash pop. However,

> git stash

this does not.

I looks like a bug to me. Could you someone please explain if this is the correct behavior ? This works as expected when I try git stash -u

Comment: The command does not remove untracked files on my system (git 2.16.2 on Linux).

Comment: @lambda: you have the first version of Git in which the bug is fixed :-)

Comment: @lambda We use 2.16.1 at work. So close :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was in fact a bug, fixed in [commit bba067d2faf047597bc76f885fb0cf87894b5ed1 by Thomas Gummerer](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bba067d2faf047597bc76f885fb0cf87894b5ed1).  This means you need Git v2.16.2 or later to have the fix.  The bug was introduced in [commit df6bba0937209d679a06addd26975593fef744f2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df6bba0937209d679a06addd26975593fef744f2), which means Git v2.13.0 or later.

(To avoid the bug, don't stash by pathspec.  The stash-by-pathspec feature was new in Git v2.13.0, in the very same commit that has the bug.)

Comment: Thanks a ton ! We use 2.16.1 at work. Time to update I guess

Comment: This just happened to me on git 2.17.1. I was able to reproduce it multiple times (edit: formatting fail, see gist): https://gist.github.com/parkerault/51a1ab6caa295b74f2a44bda8aff829d

Comment: @ParkerAult: Actually, I had a second look at your gist, and I think what happened here is that you have no tracked files at all. Your `git stash` made an empty stash, with a non-empty `-u` commit, and then deleted (because of `-u`) all *untracked* files. They'll be in your untracked-files part of the stash. If it doesn't apply correctly, that is yet another `git stash` bug.

Comment: @torek yes, it happens when you try to create a stash that _only_ has untracked files. This bit me really hard when I was trying to stash some rough proof of concept work that I wasn't ready to commit while I did maintenance on the repo.