# `git stash push -- <path>` - deletes untracked files?

Tags: git

So I just wanted to stash some changes from a particular subdirectory, and I ran `git stash push -- subdir`. This appears to have irrevocably *deleted* untracked files in that directory, like a `checkout` (they weren't saved to the stash, nor were they left in my working tree). Normal `git stash` leaves untracked files alone, which is why I expected `git stash push` to do likewise.

Git version 2.14.3 (Apple Git-98).

Questions:

- Where is it documented that this will happen without `-a`/`--all`? The closest I can see is this:

  > When pathspec is given to git stash push, the new stash entry records the modified states only for the files that match the pathspec. The index entries and working tree files are then rolled back to the state in HEAD only for these files, too, leaving files that do not match the pathspec intact.
- Is there any hope of getting my files back? Even the backup files `.xxx~` are gone.
- What should I set in my global Git configuration so that this *never* happens again?

I have several years of Git experience, and I've only very rarely managed to screw up this badly.

Comment: Luckily, I was able to piece together some of the more important bits from the compiled output (which was `.gitignore`'d and therefore not blown away by this command), but I definitely don't want to run into this footgun in the future.

Comment: It's a bug. Someone asked the same question yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49412395/1256452

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to close this as a duplicate but I'll answer a few bullet points first:

> - Where is it documented ...

It's not: it's just a bug.

> - Is there any hope of getting my files back?

Not through Git.  If your OS has "undelete" or something like MacOS "time machine" backups, look there.

> - What should I set in my global Git configuration so that this *never* happens again?

Unfortunately, there's nothing to set.  Just avoid using the special stash-by-path feature in Git versions that predate the bug fix (v2.13.0, where the feature was introduced but is buggy, until v2.16.2 where it is fixed).

(Note that you can't even alias `git stash` to a script that checks arguments, since Git won't let you override builtins.  You can use your shell to alias `git` itself, and check for the action word `stash` and then check arguments, but that's a bit painful.)